# Google Sheets formula for calculating and multiplying data ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, multiplication

Thank you in advance for your attention.

I'm attempting to create a spreadsheet that tracks employee hours on different aspects of a project.  One employee is paid $250 daily.  If this employee spends 1-8hrs on something = $250. If they spend 17-24hrs on something = $750. I don't want to track it hourly at $31.25hr.

Here's what I'm thinking but I cant get it to work:

=IF(isbetween(A1,1,8),C5*1)

C5 in this example is a cell that holds the number 250 so I can multiply (C5 * 1) or (C5 * 4) etc, based on the multiple of eight hour ranges worked. This formula by itself works fine. Though I would like to chain them together like this:

=IF(isbetween(A1,1,8),C5 * 1) AND =IF(isbetween(A1,9-16),C5 * 2) AND =IF(isbetween(A1,17,24),C5 *3 ) ....

I imagine you can't chain them this way, but is there another way to get the same effect?

Thank you again for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Add value to the results cell by $250.

You can use this formula to get  your desired output. `=IF(B1 < 9, C$5, IF ( B1 < 17, (C$5 * 2),(C$5 * 3)))`

### Sample Result:

[image]

### References:

[If](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)

Comment: Hey Babanana, 

Thank you so much for your feedback! This is perfect.  It appears that I can chain it for as long as I need to. (8 times in my particular case). 

I'm curious as to why you added the $ to "freeze" the row?  A fellow employee and I were assuming you put it in as a fail safe for something.

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Josh, the $ is for locking the cell in case you are looking to drag the formula down the reference cell will not be changed. If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)